# Automatic Properties (LINQ)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Would someone be able to explain or provide a link to a page that describes what Automatic Properties are (in relation to LINQ) in lamens terms please

Comment: Automatic properties are unrelated to LINQ. They were added to C# in the same release (3.0) as LINQ, but that's their only connection.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic properties - better call them "auto-implemented properties", are a new syntax sugar added in latest C# versions as some comment pointed out.

It consist in a property that declare its accessors without body and C# compiler creates the corresponding private fields for you:

```
public string Name
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Note that this isn't an abstract member, becase it'd be marked with the appropiate attribute "abstract"!

Additionally to that, these accessors, as non-auto-implemented ones, can have visibility attributes: private, internal, public (default behavior):

```
public string Name
{
     private get;
     internal set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an automatic property in C# 3.0:

```
public class Person 
{    
   public string FirstName  { get; set; }
   public string LastName  { get; set; }
}
```

compared to a non automatic property:

```
public class Person 
{    
   string _FirstName;
   string _LastName;

   public string FirstName 
   {
        get { return _FirstName; }
        set { _FirstName = value; }
   }

   public string LastName 
   {
        get { return _LastName; }
        set { _LastName = value; }
   }
}
```

Here's the [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/12/04/c-3-0-features-automatic-properties.aspx) by Dan Wahlin on automatic properties, from where I got the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following:

[Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

[Using Automatic Properties in LINQ](http://www.linqhelp.com/linq-tutorials/using-automatic-properties-in-linq-with-c/)